# Highcharts : selection

Tags: highcharts

I made a barchart with dates. Currently, to remove the dates, you must click on the dates in the legend. I wish delete multiple dates at once.
Let's take an example. My dates range from 1960 to 2015. If I would have on my chart the dates from 2000 to 2005, so I would like that if you click on 1960 and 1999, then all the dates between are deleted / hidden. It goes faster when many dates.
How to do ?

Here is my code :

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        colors:[
            '#7cb5ec',
            '#434348',
            '#90ed7d',
            '#f7a35c',
            '#8085e9',
            '#f15c80',
            '#e4d354',
            '#2b908f',
            '#f45b5b',
            '#91e8e1',
            '#DA70D6',
            '#1E90FF',
            '#E0F000'
            ],
        legend:{
            itemStyle:{
            fontSize:'10px',
            font:'10pt',
            color:'#000000'
          }
        },
        title:{
            style:{
                fontSize:'0px'
           }
        },
        subtitle:{
            style:{
            fontSize:'0px'
          }
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [
                '',
            ],
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 15,
            title: {
                text: 'Number',
                style:{
                    fontSize:'0px'
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {        
            shared: false,
            useHTML: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0.2,
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: '2004',
            data: [49.9],

        }, 
        {
            name: '2005',
            data: [83.6]

        }, 
        {
            name: '2006',
            data: [48.9]

        }, 
        {
            name: '2007',
            data: [69.1]

        }, 
        {
            name: '2008',
            data: [83.6]

        }, 
        {
            name: '2009',
            data: [40.9]

        },
        {
            name: '2010',
            data: [69.9]

        }, 
        {
            name: '2011',
            data: [83]

        }, 
        {
            name: '2012',
            data: [28.9]

        },
        {
            name: '2013',
            data: [40.9]

        }, 
        {
            name: '2014',
            data: [81.6]

        }, 
        {
            name: '2015',
            data: [24.9]

        },
        {
            name: '2016',
            data: [46.4]

        }]
    });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: I think that you can use legendItemClick in case of your chart. See this example: https://jsfiddle.net/u3cvfgLq/28/

Comment: Is it possible to select also the bars "limits" (for example, if you click on 2010 and 2012, remove the 3 dates, not just 2011)?
Similarly, is it possible to select multiple tracks simultaneously (eg 2005-2007 and 2010-2013)?

Comment: This is possible but I am not sure if clicking on legend is the best idea in this case. Here you can see an example how it can work: https://jsfiddle.net/u3cvfgLq/29/

Comment: That's why I asked, thank you. Of course I would prefer the method below that Mike Zavarello gave me . It is more convenient for the large number of terms. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than having each year as its own series, I would recommend that you place the years as the values in your x-axis (as categories) and then use Highcharts' native zoom function to allow users to select a certain date range.

I've updated your fiddle with some changes, which I explain below: https://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/hr28s27L/

First, in your `chart` option, I added `zoomType: 'x'` to allow users to use their mouse to zoom in on specific years. The value `x` means they can only zoom horizontally (across), which makes for a "cleaner" interaction.

```
chart: {
  type: 'column',
  zoomType: 'x'
},
```

Second, I updated your x-axis with the years as the categories/values:

```
xAxis: {
  categories: ['2004','2005','2006','2007','2008','2009','2010','2011','2012','2013','2014','2015','2016']
},
```

Lastly, I updated your series to show just the data points, which are then plotted on the y-axis:

```
series: [{
  name: 'data by year',
  data: [49.9,83.6,48.9,69.1,83.6,40.9,69.9,83,28.9,40.9,81.6,24.9,46.4]
}]
```

Here is what happens when a user clicks and drags their mouse cursor:

[image]

The shaded box is what they are selecting. Once they release the cursor, the chart will automatically adjust to show only what they chose. A "Reset Zoom" button will appear at the top right to allow them to go back to all years:

[image]

> **Update (July 19, 2016)**: I did some research on adding a simple slider element to this chart that allows users to choose from a range of years.

An updated version of my fiddle that shows this example chart with sliders can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/uvat8u05/.

The code to handle the sliders is shown below. I discovered that explicitly setting the slider values to integers using the `parseInt()` function solved a couple of problems:

- You can correctly compare the slider values to make sure users can't choose an end year that is earlier than the start year.
- The `setExtremes()` function correctly shows a single year when users choose the same start and end year.
- All x-axis labels are shown at all times. Before I added `parseInt()`, some labels disappeared when users chose different values in the sliders.

Please be sure to read the comments I've left in both the HTML and Javascript panes, as I've included additional details on why I made certain code decisions.

```
// on change handler for both sliders
$('.mySlider').bind('change', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();

    // convert the slider values to integers to make sure setExtremes() works as expected
    var slider1Val = parseInt($('input[name="slider1"]').val());
    var slider2Val = parseInt($('input[name="slider2"]').val());

    if (slider2Val < slider1Val) {
        // warn the user if they try to choose an end year that is later than the start year
        alert("You can't choose an end year that is earlier than your start year.");
    } else {
        // use setExtremes to set the x-axis ranges based on the values in the sliders
        chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(slider1Val, slider2Val);
    }

});
```

I hope this information is helpful for you.

Comment: this solution is great!
But when we zoom, can we display only the selected dates?
For example, if you select 1960 and 1961 it displays the years 1960,1961,1962,1963,1964 and 1965.
Is it possible to display only the 1960 and 1961?

Comment: Sure! All the user does is drag their cursor only over those columns. Now, if your chart is going to have quite a lot of years (I would say, more than 10), there's another demo I can point you to.

Comment: Yes on my chart there will be about 40 years. Can you help to ensure that only selected years are displayed, please?

Comment: @Lucile I've made a different version of my fiddle that includes some simple slider elements. Please be sure to read the comments in that fiddle for some details on how I made this work.

Comment: I read the comments, but I do not know how. I think everything is played on line 44.
For example, for the cursor, if both cursors are at the same value, the graph shows still two years and not only that selected.
How to change this please?

Comment: @Lucile I've updated my answer again with this requirement. You will never see just one column by itself if the user chooses the same year, but it will be directly in the middle of the redrawn chart, so that should satisfy what you need.

Comment: Iam so sorry but I do not understand very well.
There are only two problems:
1) when using the sliders if they are set on the same date, then they post from 2015 to 2016: for example, if our curseur1 is 1973 and the second in 1974, the graph displays the data in 2015 and 2016 .
2) With the drag and drop, it's perfect except for extreme years: if we choose the year 2016, then the graph displays the years 2015 and 2016

How can I solve?

Comment: @Lucile Send me an update of what you're working on in the chat section (instead of adding more comments here). I'm using the code you put in your original question, so there are no years earlier than 2004.

Comment: Where is the chat please ?

Comment: @Lucile Sorry ... it looks like you need 20 reputation to chat. I will come back to this later today and think on how this can be made better for additional years.

Comment: Ok... Thank you for your help.